# Woocommerce get variations list of product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin that save a product in Woocomerce as a sample product, so I have a hook launched just after save of this plugin to change the product to variable and init some default attributes and variations I have made it like this:

```
//change type
$product_classname = WC_Product_Factory::get_product_classname($product_id, 'variable');
$new_product = new $product_classname($product_id);
 
// link default attribute
$attributes = create_default_attributes();
$new_product->set_attributes($attributes);

// link all variation
$data_store = $product->get_data_store();
$data_store->create_all_product_variations($product);

$new_product->save();

function create_default_attributes()
{
    $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    $attributes = array();
    if (!empty($attribute_taxonomies)) {
        $tax_custom = false;
        foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax) {
            $is_custom_name = "is_custom _" . $tax->attribute_id;
            $is_custom = get_option($is_custom _name);
            if ($is_custom == 1) {
                $tax_custom = $tax;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($tax_custom) {
            $attribute_taxonomy_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax_custom->attribute_name);
            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_id($tax_custom->attribute_id);
            $attribute->set_name($attribute_taxonomy_name);
            $all_terms = get_terms($attribute_taxonomy_name);
            $option = array();
            if (!empty($all_terms)) {
                foreach ($all_terms as $term) {
                    $option[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
                }
            }
            $attribute->set_options($option);
            $attribute->set_position(0);
            $attribute->set_visible(1);
            $attribute->set_variation(1);
            $attributes[] = $attribute;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

all this thing work as expected now i need to change all variations price to the default price of sample product like this:

```
$variations=$new_product->get_children();
write_log($variations);
foreach ($variations as $value) {
    $single_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($value);
}
```

The list of $variations is empty ? why is empty ? when the hook is finished i verify in the admin area the list of all variation is still here, any idea ?

Comment: There is some missing code  for custom  `create_default_attributes()` function… So please add the code for this function or document it as your provided code is not testable for instance.

Comment: create_default_attributes() function is added if there is any why to reduce the code please let me know

Answer (score -1):

I think is a bug in woocomerce but any way i have changed the way to create variation inspired from this method:

```
 // link all variation
 $data_store = $product->get_data_store();
 $data_store->create_all_product_variations($product);
```

To:

```
    $attributes = wc_list_pluck(array_filter($product->get_attributes(), 
    'wc_attributes_array_filter_variation'), 'get_slugs');
    $possible_attributes = array_reverse(wc_array_cartesian($attributes));
    foreach ($possible_attributes as $possible_attribute) {
    $variation = wc_get_product_object('variation');
    $variation->set_parent_id($product->get_id());
    $variation->set_attributes($possible_attribute);
    $variation->set_virtual(1);
    $variation->set_downloadable(1);
    $variation->set_download_limit(-1);
    $variation->set_download_expiry(-1);
    $variation->set_regular_price($product->get_regular_price());
    $variation->set_sale_price($product->get_sale_price());
    $variation->set_date_on_sale_from($product->get_date_on_sale_from());
    $variation->set_date_on_sale_to($product->get_date_on_sale_to());
    $variation->save();
   }
```

Now i can do any change in the variation